# occurrence of a string in multiple file

Tags: perl, pm-utils

I have two files

1. input.txt
2. keyword.txt

`input.txt` has contents like:

```
.src_ref 0 "call.s" 24 first
      0x000000    0x5a80 0x0060         BRA.l 0x60
.src_ref 0 "call.s" 30 first
      0x000002    0x1bc5                RETI
.src_ref 0 "call.s" 31 first
      0x000003    0x6840                MOV R0L,R0L
.src_ref 0 "call.s" 35 first
      0x000004    0x1bc5                RETI
```

`keyword.txt` has contents like:

```
MOV
BRA.l
RETI
ADD
SUB
..
etc
```

Now I want to read this `keyword.txt` file and search it in `input.txt` file and find how many times `MOV` has occurred
how many times `BRA.l` has occurred.

So far I have managed to get it working from a single file itself.
here is the code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

sub retriver();

my @lines;
my $lines_ref;
my $count;
$lines_ref=retriver();
@lines=@$lines_ref;
$count=@lines;
print "Count :$count\nLines\n";
print join "\n",@lines;

sub retriver()
{
    my $file='C:\Users\vk41286\Desktop\input.txt';
    open FILE, $file or die "FILE $file NOT FOUND - $!\n";
    my @contents=<FILE>;

    my @filtered=grep(/MOV R0L,R0L/,@contents);
    return \@filtered;
}
```

Here I can search only `MOV` and I am unable to search other instructions like `RETI`.

Also I want to put `MOV,RETI` etc. in a `keyword.txt` file and make it generic.

OUTPUT should be:

```
MOV has occured 2  times
RETI has occured 1 time
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are not hard pressed for `perl`, a simple command line

```
 grep -f keyword.txt -c input.txt
```

should do it.

In `perl`, you would need to do also open `keyword.txt` and loop through each keyword, grepping in turn as you have done for 1 alone in your code.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `bash`-script is much simple than `perl`:

```
while read keyword
do
    occurrence =$(grep -c -F "$keyword" input.txt)
    echo "$keyword has occurred $occurrence time(s)"
done < keyword.txt
```